# Is there a way to package man pages with Quickly?

Tags: quickly, manpage

If there is, obviously an example would be helpful.

A simple "yes" isn't sufficient for the check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there isn't, but it is most probably technically possible.

As this would require modifications in Quickly and probably a technical discussion, I'd recommend following up on the [Quickly development list](https://lists.launchpad.net/quickly-talk/).